# Java request.getParameter() value in if statement

Tags: java, return-value, getparameter

I am experiencing some strange issues with request.getParameter("param") in Java. 
I am trying to test the returned value to set a boolean, nothing fancy. :)

```
String param = String.valueOf(request.getParameter("param"));
boolean paramIsAll = false;
if (param == "all"){paramIsAll = true;}

System.out.println("-"+ param +"-"+ String.valueOf(paramIsAll));
```

My output is: -all-false

???

Comment: See this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Also, an `if` statement that then performs a single line of code that returns or sets a boolean generally indicates poor coding. You can do that in a single line: `boolean paramIsAll = "all".equals(request.getParameter("param"));`. The `getParameter` method also already returns a string, there's no need for the `String.valueOf` call.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I "simplified" the code before posting and have since removed the single line if statement and "String.valueOf" call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with `if (param.equals("all")){paramIsAll = true;}`

while comparing 2 strings use [String#equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Thank you! I discovered my novice error 5 minutes after posting. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:
If(param.equalsIgnoreCase("all")){paramIsAll = true;}

Comment: Thank you! That seems like a good practice.